# How to block forward and backward browser button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I am creating a login page with `login.html` and `index.html` . When login sucess , i am calling `index.html` file throgh `jQuery` .

All the things is working fine . But i noticed **some problems.**

- when i login and i went to index.html ,But I can go back to login
  page using browser backward button .
- Also the next:  when i login ,i went to index.html page and i log out
  back to login.html page . But now I can go to index.html page with out
  login using browser forward button .

How can solve this problem ? should i block this back and forward browser button ? i am using jQuery . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

on `$(document).ready` put `window.history.forward(-1)` and same for backward